# Azure key vault integration with Databricks using Terraform/Programmatic

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

Is there any way to do key vault integration with databricks using Terraform/any programmatic. I am able to do only manually.

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, please accept it as answer. Click the check-mark beside my reply to turn green.

Answer (score 2):

In Databricks Labs Terraform provider there's [databricks_secret_scope](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/secret_scope) resource, which works pretty well with Databricks-backed secret scopes. Please check if this one is everything you need. Otherwise you can try creating [Azure Key Vault-backed scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#--create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope) and importing it as `terraform import databricks_secret_scope.object <scopeName>`. Currently it's not possible to create AKV-backed scopes programmatically, but that may (or may not) change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Databricks now supports Azure Key Vault backed secret scope in **November 13, 2019**. With this, Azure Databricks now supports two types of secret scopes—Azure Key Vault-backed and Databricks-backed.

Azure Key Vault integration with Azure Databricks is **in preview mode**. Now you can manually to use Azure Key Vault secrets in Azure Databricks, refer to this [article](https://adatis.co.uk/using-azure-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-databricks/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joey. It helps for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If it helps you, please accept it as answer. Click the checkmark beside my reply to turn to green.